# Does $x^{x} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n \ln(x)^n}{n!}$ converges uniformly for $x = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, uniform-convergence

For this exercise we can use that $e^x = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ converges uniformly in all limited subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and have to show that $x^{x} = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n \ln(x)^n}{n!}$ converges uniformly for all $x \in [0,1]$. I can show that it converges uniformly for all $x \in (0,1)$ by Dirichlet Test and $x=1$ by particular case, but I don't know if it is really true for $x = 0$. Is it possible to converge uniformly even having $ln(0)$ not existing? (As for $0^0$, we have a note saying to consider that as $1$).

Also, the next question is to show that $\int _0^1 \! x^x \, \mathrm{d}x = \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\int _0^1\! {x^n\ln(x)^n} \, \mathrm{d}x$. This would be easy if I had uniform convergence for $x = 0$, because I could use a Theorem that says that I can interchange sum and integral when convergence is uniform for all $x$ in integral limits.

Comment: It might be a helpful to use the fact that $ \lim_{x \to 0} x ln(x) = 0$; by continuity of $ x\mapsto x^n$, then $ \lim_{x \to 0} x^n ln(x)^n = 0$.

Comment: I think I got the point, but it's still confused in my head. Does it really converges uniformly even having $0$ times something non-existent for all terms of the sum?

Comment: Neither $x^x$ nor $x\ln(x)$ are defined when $x=0$...

Comment: $x\mapsto x\ln x$ is bounded on $x\in(0,1)$.

Comment: The title doesn't make sense.